# XamarinMediaManager RemoteControlReceived missing in the latest version 0.6.9

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a problem with my xamarin forms project that is using a nuget package XamarinMediaManager and in the old version(0.4.5), 
UIevent is being passed to the MediaManager, something like the ff code:

```
    public override void RemoteControlReceived(UIEvent uiEvent)
    {
        MediaManager.MediaRemoteControl.RemoteControlReceived(uiEvent);
    }
```

However after I updated the nuget to its latest version (0.6.9), a compile error appears because MediaRemoteControl property is missing.
Already visited the nuget's readme.md but no information was helpful.

Hope somebody here could help me. Thanks in Advance! :)

Comment: That was removed some time ago, you no longer need to use `RemoteControlReceived` : Commit: https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager/commit/2272a2a2f3af1f4dbd1c5a9648157cafdf2bd730 Issue: https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager/issues/442

Comment: Thanks for the response. Another question, what would be the replacement for event CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaFileChanged? is it MediaItemChanged?

Comment: Checked change logs https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager/compare/0.5.0...develop, didn't find the relationship between that two events, could you test it yourself ?